# Sonarqube Configuration Option Missing

Tags: configuration, sonarqube, rules

I cannot seem to get the Configuration Button to appear in the Top right hand corner to amend Rule contents (I can Deactivate or Change Severity but would like to be able to change contents also).

I have tried this both using the default admin/admin and my own user both of which have the Global Permission 'Administer Quality Profile and Gates' set for User and Group.

This has been tried with both the In-Built Profile (Sonar way) and my own created from a copy of 'Sonar Way'.

We are using Version 4.5.2 but the same issues seem to exist with Version 5.1 which I have also downloaded.

Don't know whether this is something stupid I am doing, a Plug-In required or possibly a Paid Option but any help or information would be gratefully received as all the Documentation and YouTube vids seem to suggest we are configured correctly and should be able to do this.

Regards,
Dave.

Comment: What to you mean by "change contents"? You mean update parameters?

Comment: Update parameters would be useful but primarily we would like to (if possible) change the Development Cost per Rule so that we can assign a series of rules to INFO which do not incur Technical Debt but are still recorded to allow future refactoring if time allows.

Comment: If you look at the following http://www.sonarqube.org/screencasts2/configuring-coding-rules/ - We do not have the Configuration Link in top right hand corener; just Settings and Admin Drop Down List.

Answer (score 0):

There's no link named "Configuration" in version 4.5. I suppose you mix management of "Quality Profiles", which requires the permission "Administer Quality Profiles and Gates" and global management console, named "Settings", which requires the permission "Administer System".

Screenshot: https://www.evernote.com/l/APs76rLwBZJHEaI7a5C7di--y3peIf42BiY